# Cached $q promise does not resolve when run in test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a directive which is downloading some content using `$http`.  I set up a cache so the content is only downloaded once no matter how many times I use the directive on the page.  The problem is in my test code, the promise never resolves!  I've called `scope.$digest` and `$rootScope.$digest` but it doesn't seem to trigger the resolve function.

The promises resolve perfectly when I actually load them in a browser.  I've set up a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oPwDQAnIpKWYyUbUS10C) to show the problem.  It has both the `$http` version a simplified `$q` version to show the problem.  Here's a copy of the directive code:

```
(function(){
    var httpPromise = null;

    angular.module("plunker").directive("httpPromise", function($http) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        compile: compile
      }

      function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
        tElement.html("<em>Promise not yet resolved.</em>");

        if(httpPromise === null) {
          console.log("making remote call (should show up once per HTML file)");

          httpPromise = $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"
          });
        }

        return link;
      }

      function link(scope, element, attributes) {
        httpPromise.then(function(){ element.html("<strong>Promise resolved!</strong>"); });
      }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `beforeEach(module("plunker"))` uses the `angular-mock` module to completely re-initialize the module **including the `$rootScope` before every test runs**.  That means the promise gets initialized using a different `$rootScope` than the directive binds to, so calling `$rootScope.$digest` doesn't do anything.

There are two ways to solve the problem.

1. Store a reference to the `$rootScope` used by the cache and call `.$digest` on that.  I've decided to do it this way and added a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ssmKipMqcWqVGn8sp3OI?p=preview) showing how.
2. Write the tests expecting the cache to be recreated every time.